# Tutorial to Create a Wunderlist-like Icon in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon, tutorial

I'm developing an application for iOS and Android and I love the style of the [Wunderlist](http://www.6wunderkinder.com/wunderlist/) icon, so I want to know if there is any tutorial about how to create this "rounded wooden drawer" effect in Photoshop.

[image: Wunderlist Icon]

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing more than vector(?) shapes with layer styles. You could take a simple rounded rectangle & add the texture. Then you double the layer, move below the current one and add a drop shadow to the above layer. Maybe it's just a mirrored linear gradient on the lower layer. The rest is bevel & emboss. It could also be that the white highlight on the lower edge is a third layer with - again - a (white) gradient.

Comment: this is way more complicated then that. I can almost bet that there is no bevel involved in this icon. Not as easy as you say it is. If i find some time i will create something like this. Would also be good tutorial to make for my blog. Once again... if i can find time

Comment: @Luuk I gave it a quick try some hours ago and it's abs. not harder than I described. Most is done with reflected/mirrored linear gradients on the lower two layers. The above is bevel & emboss. Inner shadow is also possible. The only really hard thing is to find a nice texture.

Comment: @kaiser: "...it's abs. not harder than I described." Screenshots to show just how easy would be keen, then. Otherwise, this just isn't a very good answer.

Comment: As you can see from my previous answers, I normally illustrate stuff with screenshots. But only if I think it's really necessary. The described stuff from above can be easily re-done if you got PS open and look a the layer styles window - it's not more than two styles per layer (gradient + bevel & emboss). Furthermore are layers styles resolution dependend, so posting your pixel units makes imho not much sense (you choose another resolution and stuff won't work). But thanks for saying "it's not an good answer without screenshots". If you want, you can still downvote it.